# Will bases typically precipitate silver atoms from silver ions?

Tags: redox, aqueous-solution

In class I learnt that one can dissolve many substances using acid and that this can be predicted using standard electrode potentials. For example,

$$\begin{align}
 \ce{Zn &-> Zn^{2+} + 2e^-}      &  E_0 &=  0.76~\mathrm{V} \\
 \ce{2H^+ + 2e^- &-> H2}         &+ E_0 &=  0~\mathrm{V}    \\\hline
 \ce{Zn + 2H^+ &-> H2 + Zn^{2+}} &  E_0 &=  0.76~\mathrm{V} 
\end{align} $$

And so Zinc will dissolve in acidic solutions.

I wondered what bases do and so added up the standard electrode potentials of bases and silver.

$$\begin{align}
 \ce{Ag^+ + e^- &-> Ag}                 &  E_0 &=  0.80~\mathrm{V} \\
 \ce{4OH^- &-> O2 + 2H2O + 4e^-}        &+ E_0 &= -0.40~\mathrm{V} \\\hline
 \ce{4Ag^+ + 4OH^- &-> 4Ag + O2 + 2H2O} &  E_0 &=  0.40~\mathrm{V} 
\end{align} $$

This suggests to me that basic solutions will typically precipitate a silver solid from silver ions and produce oxygen gas.

Does this make sense?

Comment: What you have written is the precipitation of silver atoms, not ions.

Comment: Also such reaction doesn't happen.

Comment: @milthoron Explain why.

Comment: I think the precipitation of $\ce{Ag2O}$ would be a faster reaction: $$\ce{2Ag^+ + 2OH^- -> Ag2O v + H2O}$$ This reaction causes $\ce{Ag^+}$ to crash out of solution before the reduction can occur. The [silver mirror (Tollens) test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tollens%27_reagent) makes use of ammonia to bring it back into solution, but it doesn't seem to be reduced by NaOH in this case, either. Maybe not enough is used to make a large amount of precipitation? Or maybe the diamminesilver(I) is has a different reduction potential.

Comment: @DGS What causes one reaction to occur over the other? Is it mainly just the Arrhenious equation and the activation energy? Is the precipitation of $\ce{Ag2O}$ a faster reaction or does it have a lower activation energy?

Comment: Those two things are ways of saying the same thing. I think it's all reaction speed. Acid/base reactions are very fast, typically, so a silver ion would have to simply collide with hydroxide, and then another hydroxide would have to pull off a proton and then you have silver(I) oxide. Precipitation reactions are also quite fast. It doesn't take much energy for two atoms of opposite charge to collide.

Comment: I guess you didn't hear about how difficult is to oxidate water. Big overpotential being serious obstacle.

Comment: @Mithoron So the oxidation of water, $\ce{2H2O -> O2 + 4H^+ + 4e^-}$, is a necessary part of the reaction mechanism for $\ce{4OH^- -> O2 + 2H2O + 4e^-}$? Makes sense, 4 hydroxide ions colliding in the right way seems a lot less probable then 2 water molecules colliding.

Comment: Both equations don't really tell much about mechanisms as they aren't elementary.